# How to add data to Firebase with Angular2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-forms

How do I push values from my form into Firebase with Angular2 approach?
I have this code so far.

**My form component**

```
export class addContentComponent {
    add: FormGroup;
    constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.add = this.fb.group({
            firstname: ['', Validators.required],
            lastname: ['', Validators.required],
                  });   };
  submitadd() { 
           const fbdbref = firebase.database().ref('add').push({

              /* I am not sure where to go from here*/

           });
    }
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitadd()"class="ui form" [formGroup]="add" novalidate>
 <input type="text" class="text-muted-signature" [formControl]="add.controls['firstname']" placeholder="FirstName" required>

 <input type="text" class="text-muted-signature" [formControl]="add.controls['lastname']"  placeholder="LastName">

  <p>
<button  [disabled]="!add.valid" type="submit">add it!</button>
                                            </p>
```

Comment: Try: `firebase.database().ref('add').push(this.add.value);`

Comment: thanks so much...that was simply fantastic, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **angularfire2** plugin which is official plugin to use firebase db with Angular2.

you can download the plugin from link: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2
Further process is available in read.md

this is how I am displaying and adding data to firebase db

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from  'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
providers:[AngularFireDatabase]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';
  model={};
  hostEl:any;
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private el:ElementRef,private renderer: Renderer2) {
this.items = db.list('/users'); // To fetch data from db
this.hostEl =  el.nativeElement;
console.log(this.items);
```

}

```
addToDb() {
  console.log(this.model);
  this.db.list('/users').push(this.model);
 }
```

}

Hope this will help you :)